# Horizontal slider not working properly after upload to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using ALS slider on my new project, it's working fine offline but after I've uploaded to the server it's not working properly, to be more specific not displaying as it should.

Anyway, the url: http://www.neisuzu.com.au/new/home/index.php

scroll to the bottom you'll see the horizontal scroller.

I've looked into it for hours still can't find what's wrong, I have a feeling that there's something that I should know but I don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like someone (ul#als-wrapper_0.als-wrapper.clearfix) is messing with the width of the container, which makes three of the elements on the list to fall below the row:

[image: Screenshot of the hidden elements]

I tried removing that and I got all of the items showed in the control:

```
<ul class="als-wrapper clearfix" id="als-wrapper_0" style="/* width: 550px; */ height: 160px;">
```

Comment: Probably as you say this is only happening after you publish to the server, I guess you are not using the same css/libraries in your local dev environment. Are you compiling your css with less or something like that?

Comment: Not really, but I aliased with the dev team and sorted it out, thanks all the same.